# Understanding a proof that $2x + 3y$ is divisible by $17$ iff $9x + 5y$ is divisible by $17$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, proof-explanation

I'm having some trouble understanding a proof on [Naoki Sato's notes](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/SatoNT.pdf) on Number Theory and I was wondering if you guys could give me some help. The problem is that I don't understand the last implication on the proof for example 1.1

> Example 1.1. Let x and y be integers. Prove that 2x + 3y is divisible by 17 iff 9x + 5y is divisible by 17.
>
> Solution. 17 | (2x + 3y) ⇒ 17 | [13(2x + 3y)], or 17 | (26x + 39y) ⇒ 17 | (9x + 5y)
>       conversely, 17 | (9x + 5y) ⇒ 17 | [4(9x + 5y)], or 17 | (36x + 20y) ⇒ 17 | (2x + 3y).

My problem is that I don't understand how does 17 | (26x + 39y) imply 17 | (9x + 5y). If you could elaborate on this step I would be most grateful.

I'm sorry if this is an obvious question but I am a beginner and I just can't get it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math.SE! This is a pretty well-written first question. I've changed your title to be more immediately informative to other users at a glance. You might notice that it's formatted nicely --- we use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/9754) to have beautiful math typography. I hope you continue to ask good questions (or perhaps answer them) in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $17\mid (26x+39y)$, and $17\mid (-17x-34y)$, then we may add to get $17\mid 9x+5y$. In general the rule is, if $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$, then $p\mid (a+b)$.

Answer (score 0):

One has $9x + 5y = (26x + 39y) - 17(x+2y)$, and $17$ clearly divides the right hand side if $17 \mid 26x + 39y$.