# $17 | 29x + 18y \implies 17 | 23x + 9y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

So, basically the title.
Prove that $17 | 29x + 18y \implies  17 | 23x + 9y$.
Plus, does then $17 | 11x + 8y$ ?

Can you please explain what's the idea for doing these type of problems .. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part:

Let us first reduce it mod 17. Hence

$$29x+18y \equiv 12x+y \pmod{17}$$
$$23x+9y \equiv 6x+9y \pmod{17}$$

since $17$ is relative ly prime to $2$, just multiply the second equation by $2$. What can you conclude?

Comment: Ok I see it, and for the second just substract $12x + y$ from $23x + 9y$ ..

Comment: So basically, theres nothing smart in this, I just need to play around with congruences until I catch the right one, right ?

Comment: @someone, it amounts to Gaussian elimination mod $17$.

Comment: @someone, for the second part, you just have another solution idea.

Comment: @someone For the first part, you just reduce numbers to the complete residue system module 17. After that, you will conclude the system is solvable if and only if its determinant is relatively prime to 17. Just like the linear equation $ax+b \equiv 0 \pmod m$ is solvable iff $\gcd(a,m) = 1$

Comment: Got it, thought it was harder. Thanks, again :)

Comment: In this case "for the first part", the system is linearly dependent, meaning that these two equations are actually the same equation.

Comment: @someone  It seems that Maged has misunderstood the 2nd part of your problem. It follows the same way as the first, e.g. see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque, you are right. I just deleted that part since its answer is the comments. Thanks for your note.

Comment: @Maged It's understandable since the wording is a bit ambiguous (such are the  vagaries of *natural* language)

Answer (score 2):

**For the first part :**

$17 \mid 29x+18y \Rightarrow 17 \mid 17x+29x+18y \Rightarrow 17 \mid 46x+18y \Rightarrow 17 \mid 2\cdot (23x+9y) \Rightarrow 17 \mid 23x+9y$

**For the second part :**

$17 \mid 29x+18y \Rightarrow 17 \mid 17x+17y+12x+y \Rightarrow 17 \mid 12x+y$

On the other hand :

$17 \mid 23x+9y \Rightarrow 17 \mid 12x+y+11x+8y \Rightarrow 17 \mid 11x+8y$

Answer (score 2):

$\left.\begin{align} 
\!\!\bmod 17\!:\ \        0\, \equiv &\, \ 18y + 29x\\
\equiv &\,\ \ \ \ \ y+12x \\
\iff\ \color{#c00}y\,\equiv&\ {-}12x\equiv\color{#c00}{5x}
\end{align}\right\}\ $ If so then  $\ \left\{ \begin{align} 
       &\,\ 23x + 9\,\color{#c00}y\\ 
\equiv &\ \ \,\ 6x + 9(\color{#c00}{5x})\\
\equiv &\,\ 51x\,\equiv\, 0
\end{align}\right\}\ $ and $\ \left\{ \begin{align} 
       &\,\ 11x + 8\,\color{#c00}y\\ 
\equiv &\, \ 11x + 8(\color{#c00}{5x})\\
\equiv &\,\ 51x\,\equiv\, 0
\end{align}\right\}$

Comment: Clear and simple!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ansatz:

> If $a(29x + 18y)\equiv 23x + 9y \bmod 17$ for some $a \in \mathbb Z$, then the result follows easily.

This has to work for all $x,y$ and so $29a \equiv 23 \bmod 17$, which gives $a \equiv 9 \bmod 17$. This $a$ also works for $18a\equiv 9 \bmod 17$.

This argument actually shows

> $17 \mid 29x + 18y \iff 17 \mid 23x + 9y$

Here is an explanation.

Consider the matrix $\pmatrix{ 29 & 18 \\ 23 & 9}$.
Its determinant is $-153$, which is $0$ mod $17$.
Therefore, its two rows are linearly dependent mod $17$.
In particular, the second row is a nonzero multiple of the first row, mod $17$, which implies the result, even without computing an explicit multiplier. (Here it is important that $17$ is prime.)

For the second part, consider the matrix $\pmatrix{ 29 & 18 \\ 11 & 8}$.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2947271/589

Comment: Thanks but I really prefer doing it using just number theory if possible, as I have no knowledge in linear algebra (even matrices and determinants) ..

Comment: @someone, just compute $9(29x + 18y)$ mod $17$.

Comment: Oh, but whats the trick with 9 ?

Comment: @someone $17$ is prime, so $9$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $17$.

Comment: Actually that gives me just $17 | 13x + 9y$ if I've done it right

Comment: Sorry, got it now .. But still cant see a way to do these problems in general

Comment: Ok, I got it. So this works only if modulo is prime, right ?

Comment: @someone, in general if the determinant is invertible mod the modulo.

Comment: @someone While this works generally it's a bit overkill here because we can easily solve for $\,y\,$ given that its coef is $\equiv 1\pmod{17}\,$  see my answer.